# Selenium Webdriver: (python) wait for element to not be present (not working)

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing, element

I'm learning about the Selenium web drivers and have started using python to test websites. I'm having issues with the wait for element not to be present code, as it seems to be timing out.

This is the code I have so far.

```js
def test_(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/abc")
        driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").send_keys("username")
        driver.find_element_by_id("Password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("password")
        driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
        for i in range(60):
            try:
                if not self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".blockUI"): break
            except: pass
            time.sleep(1)
        else: self.fail("time out")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ChangeTaskGridM']/table/thead/tr/th[1]/a").click()
        for i in range(60):
            try:
                if not self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".blockUI"): break
            except: pass
            time.sleep(1)
        else: self.fail("time out")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ChangeTaskGridM']/table/thead/tr/th[2]/a").click()
        for i in range(60):
            try:
                if not self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".blockUI"): break
            except: pass
            time.sleep(1)
        else: self.fail("time out")
```

I'm not sure why it's timing out. If I remove the blockUI it will run to fast and I also don't want to put manual breaks in between. Any ideas?

Current code to detect is_element_present

```js
for i in range(60):
            try:
                if not self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".blockUI"): break
            except: pass
            time.sleep(1)
        else: self.fail("time out")
```

Comment: Please add the code for `is_element_present`

Comment: I've added it at the bottom for clarification

Comment: I meant the implementation of `is_element_present`, not how you call it.

Comment: Please tell us where in the code it is timing out.

Comment: I'm sorry that I din't follow up on this question. I gave up on it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code to check presence of that element you should use ExpectedConditions.  Please read the [doc for waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html).  the presence_of_element_located() is probably the one of interest to you.

Comment: I think this would of worked but I'm no longer working on the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You put sleep in wrong place, i believe this is what you wanted:

```
for i in range(60):
            try:
                if not self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".blockUI"): 
                    break
                else:
                    time.sleep(1)
            except: pass
```

also in Python else after for will be always performed after successful end of loop, no wonder you get self.fail("time out") every time