# print only one 'tr' tag in 'tbody' - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

> I am trying to print the content of only one 'tr' tag in 'tbody'.
>   I used this code to print all 'tr's in 'tbody' but Python doesn't print me the 'tr's after Berlin. I used this url : https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/?fbclid=IwAR0xb7zTV0vstu-sLE3ByHZVSw89HyqjSwMhpfXT23RwcFqR57za2J_l7XQ.
>   This is the table I want to print completely: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i869g.png

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/?fbclid=IwAR0xb7zTV0vstu-sLE3ByHZVSw89HyqjSwMhpfXT23RwcFqR57za2J_l7XQ"
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")



allStat = {}

table_body = soup.find('tbody')
table_rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for i in table_rows:
    region = i.find('td', class_ = 'region').get_text()
    confirmed = i.find('td', class_ = 'confirmed').get_text()
    deaths = i.find('td', class_= 'deaths' ).get_text()

    allStat.update({region: [confirmed,deaths]})
print(allStat)
```

Comment: could you please wait for the element to be located within `HTML` source ? otherwise use the built in `time` library. [check](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), also am voting down for that question as it's completely duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver: (python) wait for element to not be present (not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725439/selenium-webdriver-python-wait-for-element-to-not-be-present-not-working)

Comment: I don't understand how to make it work like I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get(
    "https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/")

btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "button.btn.fnktable__expand").click()

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

[image]